# Is it ok to instantiate many short-lived Dictionary<string, MyClass> or better to object-pool?

Tags: garbage-collection

I have a method that reads some values from the DB and then yields a Dictionary - could be many thousand times.

```
public IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, MyClass>> GetValues()
{
   var results = new Dictionary<string, MyClass>();
   // ... fill data from data reader

   yield return results;
}
```

Consumer of this method only iterates over the result and uses the dictionary in a reading manner.
So... in regards to garbage collection and memory continuity: Would it make sense to do something like this?

```
private Dictionary<string, MyClass> _resultHolder = new Dictionary<string, MyClass>();

public IEnumerable<ReadOnlyDictionary<string, MyClass>> GetValues()
{
   // Don't want the previous record values, so clear
   _resultHolder.Clear();
   // ... fill data from data reader

   yield return _resultHolder;
}
```

As far as I remember there are different levels to the garbage collector... So will this result only ever end up in Level 0 anyway and therefore not cause any problems in regard to memory fragmentation?
Would this kind of object pooling be premature optimization?

Comment: a) In most cases, DB operations dwarf any heap memory related performance issues b) Temporary objects are handled more efficient than reused objects. That’s even visible in your code, as you now need a `Clear()` operation. So you’re getting potential semantic problems with the shared `Dictionary` instance for no benefit.